# Why isn't the LCD display on my Canon 750D flipping when I rotate it?

Tags: canon, lcd, rear-lcd

I'm kind of new to this so sorry if this is kind of a basic question.

I have a Canon EOS 750D which has been working just fine.
However today when I was going to shoot when I flip the screen around the image display appears upside down. It has stopped rotating and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

[image]

This has worked fine before where when I rotate the display, the content on the LCD is also rotated.

Any idea on how I resolve this?

Comment: Try turning off your camera, removing the battery for an hour, and checking again. I suspect this won't solve the problem, so you probably have a hardware problem and need to go to a repair shop.

Comment: Stupid hint: nothing has changed in the preferences ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a camera fault. Most possibly a hardware problem of the position sensor.

If the camera is still new, make a warranty claim. This is an obvious bug.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[image: canon 750D lcd hinge 'flip' switch broken]

The Canon 750D I'm working on is in mint condition and less than two years old.

There's no signs of abuse, no dents, no scratches.

You can see in the middle of the picture a piece of black plastic.  That is a part of the square silver micro switch that broke off.

Comment: This is not clearly an answer. It could be interpreted as a "me too" post. Presumably the switch is the cause of the problem, but it isn't clear whether this camera has the same problem that the OP has or whether the switch is necessarily the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it is the motion sensor in the screen that has malfunctioned and the only way to repair this problem is to change the whole screen as the sensor it not sold on its own, I had it looked at by a friend that works for an electronics repair shop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this small switch and a nice Internet user shared the video demonstration of the repair. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DPBDk4ZVJU) and congratulation from belgium for sharing